# Hyperledger fabric creating channel error on the cluster

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have tried to generate hyperledger fabric network, but I've falled in the trouble creating a channel.

I have 3 orderers, 4 kafkas, 3 zookeepers, 2 peers.

1. configtx.yaml

`Organizations:
   - &orderers
        Name: orderers
        ID: orderers
        MSPDir: /certs/orderers/msp
        Policies: &orderersPolicies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('orderers.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('orderers.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('orderers.admin')"
    - &peers
        Name: peers
        ID: peers
        MSPDir: /certs/peers/msp
        Policies: &peersPolicies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('peers.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('peers.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('peers.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1st
              Port: 7051
Profiles:
    PeersGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Addresses:
                - orderer1st:7050
                - orderer2nd:7050
                - orderer3rd:7050
            Organizations:
                - *orderers
        Consortiums:
            FabricConsortium:
              Organizations:
                - *peers
    PeersChannel:
        Consortium: FabricConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *peers`

2. I set CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=peers on the fabric-ca-tools container and send command `peer channel create -f /artifacts/peers-dev-channel.pb -c peers-dev -o orderer1st:7050`
3. The orderer1st side logs like below

`2018-09-03 19:03:41.917 UTC [orderer/common/server] Deliver -> DEBU 2d7 Starting new Deliver handler
2018-09-03 19:03:41.917 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 2d8 Starting new deliver loop for 10.56.2.84:48428
2018-09-03 19:03:41.918 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 2d9 Attempting to read seek info message from 10.56.2.84:48428
2018-09-03 19:03:41.918 UTC [orderer/common/server] Broadcast -> DEBU 2da Starting new Broadcast handler
2018-09-03 19:03:41.918 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 2db Starting new broadcast loop for 10.56.2.84:48430
2018-09-03 19:03:41.919 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 2dc [channel: peers-dev] Broadcast is processing config update message from 10.56.2.84:48430
2018-09-03 19:03:41.919 UTC [orderer/common/msgprocessor] ProcessConfigUpdateMsg -> DEBU 2dd Processing config update tx with system channel message processor for channel ID peers-dev
2018-09-03 19:03:41.919 UTC [orderer/common/msgprocessor] ProcessConfigUpdateMsg -> DEBU 2de Processing config update message for channel peers-dev
2018-09-03 19:03:41.920 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2df == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers ==
2018-09-03 19:03:41.920 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2e0 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2018-09-03 19:03:41.920 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2e1 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers ==
2018-09-03 19:03:41.920 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2e2 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2018-09-03 19:03:41.920 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2e3 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/orderers/Writers ==
2018-09-03 19:03:41.921 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 2e4 0xc42000e1a0 gate 1536001421921206508 evaluation starts
2018-09-03 19:03:41.921 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2e5 0xc42000e1a0 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2018-09-03 19:03:41.921 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2e6 0xc42000e1a0 processing identity 0 with bytes of 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
2018-09-03 19:03:41.921 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2e7 0xc42000e1a0 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected orderers, got peers)
2018-09-03 19:03:41.922 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2e8 0xc42000e1a0 principal evaluation fails
2018-09-03 19:03:41.922 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 2e9 0xc42000e1a0 gate 1536001421921206508 evaluation fails
2018-09-03 19:03:41.922 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2ea Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/orderers/Writers
2018-09-03 19:03:41.922 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2eb == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/orderers/Writers
2018-09-03 19:03:41.922 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 2ec Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ orderers.Writers ]
2018-09-03 19:03:41.923 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2ed Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-09-03 19:03:41.923 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2ee == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-09-03 19:03:41.923 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 2ef Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Consortiums.Writers Orderer.Writers ]
2018-09-03 19:03:41.923 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2f0 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Writers
2018-09-03 19:03:41.923 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2f1 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2018-09-03 19:03:41.923 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 2f2 [channel: peers-dev] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 10.56.2.84:48430 because of error: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
2018-09-03 19:03:41.923 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 2f3 Closing Broadcast stream
2018-09-03 19:03:41.925 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 2f4 Error reading from 10.56.2.84:48428: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2018-09-03 19:03:41.925 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 2f5 Closing Deliver stream`

5. I don't know why this problem occurred because I already set channel information on the configtx.yaml file correctly and set admin MSPID and MSPPATH when I send commnad.

Comment: I solved this problem.

Comment: I recently came across the same problem, can you share your solution?

Comment: it depends on your fabric version, and in my case, I use 1.2. Orderers create their own channel (system channel) when they boot up. My fault is use same channel name between system channel and application channel. I referenced hyperledger cello project source code[https://github.com/hyperledger/cello]